# Azure VMs. SharePoint 2013 -no hA farm

Tags: virtual-machine, azure

I just created SharePoint 2013 -no HA farm with Virtual machines on Azure. I worte down everything while creating passwords, domain name...etc. Now I am trying to connect to VM and can not login. It is failing. I tried Administrator user name and used all the passwords. So my question is what is my username and what is my password that I have created. Please help me.Thanks

-Satyen

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have tested in my lab. here are some accounts about the SharePoint:

The VMs’ username will set by yourself. The **username** is the admin username for the virtual machines and the Active Directory domain.
**SQL service account**: username is sqlserver, account is used to run MSSQLSERVER and SQLSERVERAGENT.
**SharePoint setup account**: username is spsetup, account is used to setup SharePoint.
**Farm account**, username is sp_farm, account is used to configure and manage server farm, act as the application pool identity for the SharePoint Central Administration Web site and run the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow.
[The details about SharePoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e84j2.png)
If the VMs’ username or password was lost, we can **use Azure portal to reset the password**, in that page we can find the username and reset the password.
[How to use Azure portal to reset the password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3k1O.png)

If you still have questions, welcome to post back here. Thanks.

Best Regards,